# pass a variable in url in javaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html

How to make the below script pass the javascript values to the url of the href link?

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(name) {
var elemA = name;


window.location.href = "view.php?search=elemA";

}
</script>
```

Comment: By _concatenating_ a string and the content of your variable … `window.location.href = "view.php?search=" + elemA;`

Comment: (Should probably add proper URL encoding while you’re at it.)

Comment: Consider using template strings (back ticks `\``)

Answer (score 2):

You can attach a variable to a string like this. You may have to use the function `encodeURIComponent` to avoid errors with whitespaces etc.

```
function myFunction(name) {
  var elemA = name;
  window.location.href = "view.php?search=" + encodeURIComponent(elemA);
}
```

Comment: The correct function to use would be `encodeURIComponent`, applied on the parameter value only.

Answer (score 0):

Use this...

```
window.location.href = "view.php?search="+elemA;
```